# Display Post Meta Values in Arrays

Tags: php, wordpress, post, meta

I have a following function:

```
function frontend_add_age_group_field ( $fields ) {
  $fields['event']['event_age_group'] = array(
    'label'       => __( 'Age Group', 'event_manager' ),
    'type'        => 'multiselect',
    'options'  => array(    
                'kids' => __( 'Kids (7-10 Years)', 'wp-event-manager' ),
                'youngsters' => __( 'Youngsters (10-14 Years)', 'wp-event-manager' ),
                'youth' => __( 'Youth (15-25)', 'wp-event-manager' ),
                'adults' => __( 'Adults (25+)', 'wp-event-manager' ),
             ),
    'required'    => true,
    'priority'    => 4,
  );
  return $fields;
}
```

For instance, the values in the database against a post are:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:10:"youngsters";i:1;s:5:"youth";i:2;s:6:"adults";}
```

I am trying to retrieve these values on front-end which I am unable to get using this function. I am getting Nothing as an output:

```
function get_event_age_group()
{
    global $post;

    $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_event_age_group' );
    $age_groups = $data['options'];
    return $age_groups; 

}
```

Can anyone help why I am unable to get the data? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the output with below function. Although I am not that much experienced in coding. I know their must be a better way of doing this but I was able to accomplish this somehow. Here is the function that worked for me. It might help someone.

```
/*Function to get Age Groups from Events */
function get_event_age_group()
{
    global $post;

    $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_event_age_group', false);
    //$age_groups = $data['options'];
    foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {

    switch ($value[0]) {
        case "kids": 
            echo "Kids (7-10 Years)";
        break;
        case "youngsters": 
            echo "Youngsters (10-14 Years)";
        break;
        case "youth": 
            echo "Youth (15-25)";
        break;
        case "adults": 
            echo "Adults (25+)";
        break;
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    switch ($value[1]) {
        case "kids": 
            echo "Kids (7-10 Years)";
        break;
        case "youngsters": 
            echo "Youngsters (10-14 Years)";
        break;
        case "youth": 
            echo "Youth (15-25)";
        break;
        case "adults": 
            echo "Adults (25+)";
        break;
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    switch ($value[2]) {
        case "kids": 
            echo "Kids (7-10 Years)";
        break;
        case "youngsters": 
            echo "Youngsters (10-14 Years)";
        break;
        case "youth": 
            echo "Youth (15-25)";
        break;
        case "adults": 
            echo "Adults (25+)";
        break;
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    switch ($value[3]) {
        case "kids": 
            echo "Kids (7-10 Years)";
        break;
        case "youngsters": 
            echo "Youngsters (10-14 Years)";
        break;
        case "youth": 
            echo "Youth (15-25)";
        break;
        case "adults": 
            echo "Adults (25+)";
        break;
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
}
```